# split comma separated data columns to 2 rows in a DataTable c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, lambda

I am having a datatable with following data

```
Users    |  Department          |   Location
-------------------------------------------- 
User 1   |  Account,Sales       |   location 1
User 1   |  Finance             |   location 2
User 2   |  Sales,Customer Care |   location 3
User 3   |  Support             |   location 5
```

I would like to get the result as follows

```
Users    |  Department     |    Location
---------------------------------------------------
User 1   |  Account        |    location 1 
User 1   |  Sales          |    location 1 
User 1   |  Finance        |    location 2 
User 2   |  Sales          |    location 3 
User 2   |  Customer Care  |    location 3 
User 3   |  Support        |    location 5
```

**Is there any way other than for loop & foreach loop** to achieve this result.
I am having a huge amount of data(nearly 1 million records) in the datatable which are fetched from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a one-time-task for your datatable i don't think there is a more efficient way than looping over all datasets and check for `,`. Sorting the data (or converting it to any appropriate data structure) to increase performance of the actual seperations and running the seperation-task afterwards will take just as long as seperating your datasets right away when you hit a dataset containing a `,`.

So yes, there are several ways to accomplish this, but none of them will provide better performance than a simple loop.